# Difference between $(array).each(...) and $.each(array, ...) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have an array in a JavaScript variable that I want to iterate through, I usually use jQuery's `.each()` function like this:

```
var myArray = ["foo", "bar"];
$(myArray).each(function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

But I can achieve the same effect by passing in my array as an argument to the `.each()` function, like this:

```
var myArray = ["foo", "bar"];
$.each(myArray, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

[Obligatory but unnecessary JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stamminator/snksutha/)

This question can apply to basically any other jQuery function as well, not just `.each()`. Is there a functional difference between these two different usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference in the way they function.

The main difference is going to be that using `$.each()` allows you to pass in an array whereas using `$().each()` requires you to have a constructed jQuery object to use as the context.

There is a slight difference in readability, but that is negligible.

If you were to look at [jQuery's source code](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js), you could also confirm this, as `$.each` is simply just a call to prototype's definition of each:

```
// Execute a callback for every element in the matched set.
each: function( callback ) {
    return jQuery.each( this, callback );
},
```